# extending cursorAdapter, what constructor to use

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter, android-cursor

I'm trying to fill a listview with a database query. I'm using a custom adapter that extends cursor adapter. I don't know what constructor to use. When i use the default one:

```
public AdapterListview(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

It works fine, but i'm getting a warning that is deprecated. I did some research and it looks like it is recommended to use the following and use 0 for the flags.

```
public AdapterListview(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    super(context, c, flags);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

But it looks like it is not supported for anything under API 11, and my project is targetting API 8. Nevertheless I tried it anyway and i get the following logcat error:

```
10-27 02:11:22.230: E/AndroidRuntime(491): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-27 02:11:22.230: E/AndroidRuntime(491): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.CursorAdapter.<init>
10-27 02:11:22.230: E/AndroidRuntime(491):  at com.mangodeveloper.mcathomie.AdapterListview.<init>(AdapterListview.java:14)
10-27 02:11:22.230: E/AndroidRuntime(491):  at com.mangodeveloper.mcathomie.ActivityStats.onCreate(ActivityStats.java:36)
10-27 02:11:22.230: E/AndroidRuntime(491):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-27 02:11:22.230: E/AndroidRuntime(491):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
10-27 02:11:22.230: E/AndroidRuntime(491):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
10-27 02:11:22.230: E/AndroidRuntime(491):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-27 02:11:22.230: E/AndroidRuntime(491):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
10-27 02:11:22.230: E/AndroidRuntime(491):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-27 02:11:22.230: E/AndroidRuntime(491):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-27 02:11:22.230: E/AndroidRuntime(491):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-27 02:11:22.230: E/AndroidRuntime(491):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-27 02:11:22.230: E/AndroidRuntime(491):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-27 02:11:22.230: E/AndroidRuntime(491):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-27 02:11:22.230: E/AndroidRuntime(491):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-27 02:11:22.230: E/AndroidRuntime(491):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So i feel at a loss for what i'm supposed to do.

Comment: Support library v4 includes CursorAdapter. You can use the one from [support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CursorAdapter from [Support Library v4](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) has the `(Contex, Cursor, int)` constructor. Set up the project to use the library and in your code replace `import CursorAdapter;` with `import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;` .

Comment: totally worked. i've always had the library, but i guess it's never come up cause i didn't add it to build path.